# Clang-Format wrongly detects & operator (boost serialization)

Tags: c++, boost, clang-format

I tried to apply clang-format (11) on a file containing a boost serializable file with content along the lines

```
class MyClass
{
    int _myNumber;
    int &_myRefNumber;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) const
    {
        ar & _myNumber;
    }
}
```

now suppose I like references on the left, I set `PointerAlignment : Left` and get

```
class MyClass
{
    int _myNumber;
    int& _myRefNumber;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int /*version*/) const
    {
        ar& _myNumber;
    }
}
```

which is correct for the refrence, but also nastily moves the `&` operator to the left. Is there any graceful way with clang-format to keep the operator with whitespaces while moving references? For now the only way I see is to disable clang-format for those lines.

Comment: Old [Opened issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/20572).

Comment: @Jarod42 looks like that should be an answer.

Comment: My stance here is that this kind of code is sufficiently rare that I don't mind it getting weird. And in all other cases where clang-format I mandate manual linebreaks using `//`.